how can I check where wordpress media directory is set to upload files
I initially created my wordpress site in a directory named mysite.com/new , then copied the files to the root directory mysite.com/
Now images uploaded to mysite.com are still stored in  mysite.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2024/ uploads folder instead of going to mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2024 . In the image gallery of mysite.com, the newly uploaded images appear blank. I need to find the settings my root folder is using to save uploaded files
have checked the wp-config file but nothing there to suggest file upload path. Any suggestions please help
I have checked the wp-config file but found no settings there suggesting upload file path

Wordpress makes a post for each image that is uploaded containing the absolute URL.  So when you move the whole structure you will have to change the URL in each post to the new absolute URL with PHPMyadmin. Thats tricky.
Now, if you only have a few images so do upload them as usual and go to your posts and attach them again.
